# How to list all active sc (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I recently heard about the `sc` command.

You could do the following:

```
sc stop ""
```

Now I want to know if I can list these processes.
Even better, if I could use them in something like:

```
if sc "program" = active do this
```

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I already did my best I just want to list active programs with the sc function in powershell, and I want powershell to do something if a certian program is active

Comment: if (get-process -Name "HERENAME") {#Process exists do something}

Comment: thanks @guiwhatsthat that was exactly what I was looking for. 1 last quistion, How do I hide the error message if the thing is not active?

Comment: Hi - removed "thanks" language which isn't needed, tweaked formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get-process` to find the process of your application.

Example:

```
if (Get-Process -Name "ProcessName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    #Process Exists DO something } 
else {
    #Process doesn't exist do something  

 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed